# if else function in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was trying to do a loop. However, when I input the required value (value is 1), I return me the alert part which I put in.

```
var ctp
        if (NumberPasses === '1') {
            ctp = 0.93
        }
        if (NumberPasses === '2') {
            ctp = 0.90
        }
        if (NumberPasses === '3') {
            ctp = 0.85
        }
        else return (
            alert("Number of tube pass: Only 1, 2 or 3!")
        )
```

So whenever I key in the value '1' or '2', it shows the "Number of tube pass: Only 1, 2 or 3!". However, when I key in '3', the loop accept the value and assign ctp = 0.85.

Comment: can you explain bit more

Comment: we don't know what is `NumberPasses`.. how are we supposed to help you? it might be potentially a int, and so the `===` fails for the typecheck

Comment: The NumberPasses is a user Input using the useState. If i remove the if else function, the system is able to register the input value for NumberPasses but it does go through the if else function

Comment: did you mean
if() ... else if() ... else if() ... else
instead of
if() ... if() ... if() ... else ?
If your NumberPasses is not '3' you will always get your alert

Answer (score 1):

Use else if

```
var ctp
        if (NumberPasses === '1') {
            ctp = 0.93
        }
        else if(NumberPasses === '2') {
            ctp = 0.90
        }
        else if(NumberPasses === '3') {
            ctp = 0.85
        }
        else return (
            alert("Number of tube pass: Only 1, 2 or 3!")
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use else if this way:

```
var ctp; 
    if (NumberPasses === '1') {
        ctp = 0.93
    }
    else if (NumberPasses === '2') {
        ctp = 0.90
    }
    else if (NumberPasses === '3') {
        ctp = 0.85
    }
    
   return alert("Number of tube pass: Only 1, 2 or 3!");
```

Explanation about issue in your code:

In your case when you pass '1':

- It checks first if for NumberPasses === '1' which evalutes as true
- ctp value is assigned 0.93
- Then it checks for NumberPasses === '2' which evalutes as false
- Then it checks for NumberPasses === '3' which evalutes as false
- It goes to else case and returns alert("Number of tube pass: Only 1, 2 or 3!");

Similarly it happens for '2':

- It checks first if for NumberPasses === '1' which evalutes as false
- Then it checks for NumberPasses === '2' which evalutes as true
- ctp value is assigned 0.90
- Then it checks for NumberPasses === '3' which evalutes as false
- It goes to else case and returns alert("Number of tube pass: Only 1, 2 or 3!");